# "Thinking in C++": operation of "Stash" library

Tags: c++, pointers, allocation

Stash library in "Thinking in C++" by Bruce Eckel:

Basically he seems to be setting up an array-index-addressable interface (via fetch) to a set of entities that are actually stored at random memory locations, without actually copying those data entities, in order to simulate for the user the existence of an actual contiguous-memory data block.  In short, a contiguous, indexed address map.  Do I have this right?  Also, his mapping is on a byte-by-byte basis; if it were not for this requirement (and I am unsure of its importance), I believe that there may be simpler ways to generate such a data structure in C++.  I looked into memcpy, but do not see how to actually copy data on a byte-by-byte basis to create such an indexed structure.

Prior posting:

This library appears to create a pointer assemblage, not a data-storage assemblage.
Is this true?  (Applies to both the C and C++ versions.)  Thus the name "stash" might be a little misleading, as nothing but pointers to data stashed elsewhere is put into a "stash," and Eckel states that "the data is copied."

Background:  Looking at “add” and “inflate,” the so-called “copying” is equating pointers to other pointers (“storage” to “e” in “add” and “b” to “storage” in “inflate”).  The use of “new” in this case is strange to me, because storage for data is indeed allocated but “b” is set to the address of the data, and no data assignments seem to take place in the entire library.  So I am not sure what the point of the “allocation” by “new” is when the allocated space is apparently never written into or read from in the library.  The “element” to be added exists elsewhere in memory already, and seemingly all we are doing is creating a sequential pointer structure to each byte of every “element” desired to be reference-able through CStash.  Do I understand this library correctly?

Similarly, it looks as though “stack” in the section “Nested structures” appears actually to work only with addresses of data, not with data. I wrote my own linked-list stack successfully, which actually stores data in the stack nodes.

Comment: I need at least 15 character to post this : tl;dr Could you sum it up in a clearer way ?

Comment: please post a complete but minimal example

Comment: `Why can't I do this` - because `qp[i]` is an `int`, whereas `&q[i]` is an `int *`.

Comment: Similarly, it looks as though “stack” in the section “Nested structures” appears actually to work only with addresses of data, not with data.                                                H2CO3:  If I understand you, although qp was defined previously as a pointer (int*), qp[i] is an int; I guess I don't know how that works.

Comment: @LearningCpp because the `[]` operator does that (dereferencing).

Comment: H2CO3:  Thank you very much!  In other words, I guess you are saying that qp[i] = *(qp+i) = q[i].  That was VERY helpful.  Now all I need is to know whether I'm understanding correctly with my discussion on the Tiny C-like Library in "Thinking in C++."